# File Handling - Value is being added two times instead of one

Tags: c++

When I run my code it is adding the value of 81 two times. Why ???

Write a program to read the contents of file Squares.txt and display the
sum of all the numbers, the average of all the numbers, the largest
number and the smallest number in a file named Analysis.txt.
Content in Squares.txt :

```
Number Square
3        9
5        25
1        1
7        49
9        81
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    ifstream file ;
    char arra[100];
    int num1,num2,avg;
    int sum=0 ;
    int smallest = 9999 ;
    int highest = -999 ;
    int count= 0 ;
    cout<<"Open file square.txt..."<<endl ;
    file.open("/Users/kchumun/Documents/Xcode/Labsheet 8(3)/square2.txt") ;
    if(!file){
        cout<<"File cannot be opened !"<<endl ;
    }else {
        cout<<"File opened !"<<endl;
        file.get(arra,100) ;
        while(!file.eof()){
            file>>num1;
            file>>num2 ;
            sum+=num2;
            count++ ;
            if(num2<smallest){
                smallest = num2 ;
            }
            if (num2>highest) {
                highest = num2 ;
            }
        }
    }
    file.close() ;
    avg= sum / count ;
    cout<<"Sum= "<<sum<<endl ;
    cout<<"Average= "<<avg<<endl;
    cout<<"Highest= "<<highest<<endl ;
    cout<<"Smallest= "<<smallest<<endl;
    
    ofstream File ;
    cout<<"Open file Analysis "<<endl ;
    if(!File){
        cout<<"Error !" ;
    }else{
        File.open("/Users/kchumun/Documents/Xcode/Labsheet 8(3)/Analysis.txt");
        File<<"Sum= "<<sum<<endl ;
        File<<"Averagem= "<<avg<<endl;
        File<<"Highest= "<<highest<<endl ;
        File<<"Smallest= "<<smallest<<endl ;
    }
    File.close();
    cout<<"Operation completed !";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(!file.eof())` often causes duplication errors. Details here: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 1):

This style of code is incredibly common but also incredibly wrong

```
while(!file.eof()){
        file>>num1;
        file>>num2;
```

Like this instead please

```
while (file >> num1 >> num2) {
```

The problem with your code is a misunderstanding of how `eof` works. `Eof` tests if you are at the end of the file right? No, wrong. In reality `eof` tests if your last read failed because you were at the end of file. A subtly different thing, and this difference explains why your loop seems to read the last item twice.

If you do use `eof` you should use it **after** reading to test if the **last** read failed. Not before reading to predict if the next read will fail.

Comment: General rule: 1. Read data. 2. Make sure you read data. 3. Make sure data read is with a valid range. 4. If everything is good up to this point, use data. If you try to do a read out of order, like testing for validity before reading, sooner or later it will fail.